# Double click into cell under text is located and fill value from prepared xlsx

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am able open particular website, but I need to detect text element in website and double click into cell which is located under this text string 'Ext. financing ref #' (there is no button, just text string). After detection this text element 'Ext. financing ref #' double click into cell located under text element and fill value from loaded xlsx document and save this changes (but there is multiple save buttons located in webpage (see prtscrn).

So far I have this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm

options = Options()
options.binary_location = r'C:\Users\My.Name\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('https://www.webpage_to_open.com/')


df=pd.read_excel("com.xlsx")
order_id=list(df['order_id'])
destination_efr=list(df['efr'])

df

speed=1.8 # don't go below ~0.6
for i in tqdm(range(0,df.shape[0])):
time.sleep(speed)
o_id=order_id[i]
efr_id=destination_efr[i]
m_web="https://www.webpage_to_open.com/en/orders/"+ str(o_id)+"/contract"
browser.get(m_web)
time.sleep(speed)
#next section is already not correct
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//[text()="Ext. financing ref #"]'))).Click();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdfHK.png)